# Dependency Injection In Class Library

Tags: .net, reflection, dependency-injection, architecture, autofac

Having a solution with two projects I've ran into a DI problem.
The solution consists of a class library and a WebApi2 app(which consumes the class library and exposes an api).

I've defined a Autofac.module in the class library which sets up all the DI in the project.

In the WebApi2 project I create the DI container (using Autofac.WebApi2) and load the module from the class library. Now when the api controllers in the WepApi2 project requests services in the class library they get created with all their dependencies, this all works great!

The problem is that I now in the class library need to instantiate some classes from a string(that eventually comes from the DB), as far as I know the only way to do this i by using reflection, so I do like this:

```
var ruleType = Type.GetType(rule.RuleImplementation.Implementation);
var rule = (IRule)Activator.CreateInstance(ruleType,param1,param2);
```

The problem is that the class implementing the IRule interface also has dependencies which need to get resolved, and this is what made me banging my on my keyboard for a while now.

Is it possible to somehow use reflection and autoFac together to instantiate the objects? I still need to be able to pass my params into the object as well.

... Or is there a way to somehow access the container (which was created in the webApi2 assembly) and use that to resolve it? I guess this would be some sort of service pattern which I believe is considered an anti pattern.

How do I proceed? All input is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Creating your components using `Activator.CreateInstance` is a bad idea, because it basically means you are reimplementing the logic the container is doing for you, but without the features and safety guards that the DI library provides you with.

> I've defined a Autofac.module in the class library which sets up all the DI in the project.

This is where the source of your trouble lies. There should be only one place in the application where object graphs are composed (and registered) and this is the application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This Composition Root can be seen as a separate layer that lies on top of your presentation layer (Web API), even though it is quite common to have both the Composition Root (layer) and the Presentation Layer reside in the same project.

Doing this removes the problem, because inside your composition root you already have access to the container.

A good solution to allow rules to be created using some definition that comes from the database is by defining an `IRuleActivator` abstraction. This abstraction can be defined in your library and implemented inside the composition root. This allows the implementation to wrap the container, while the library stays oblivious to the existence of the container:

```
// Defined in the library
public interface IRuleActivator
{
    IRule GetRule(RuleData rule);
}

// Defined in the Compostion Root
public sealed class AutofacRuleActivator : IRuleActivator
{
    private readonly IComponentContext context;
    public AutofacRuleActivator(IComponentContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IRule GetRule(RuleData rule) {
        Type ruleType = Type.GetType(rule.RuleImplementation.Implementation);
        return (IRule)this.context.Resolve(ruleType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create factory for IRule creation:

```
public IRuleFactory
{
   IRule CreateRule(params);
}
```

For parameters I would go with some kind of the IParamsProviders which can be injected then into implementation of the IRuleFactory, the RuleImpl is just your implementation of the object construction, can be reflection as well:

```
public class RuleFactory : IRuleFactory
{
    public RuleFactory(IParamsProvider provider)
    {
        ...
    }

    public IRule CreateRule()
    {
        return new RuleImpl(provider.Param1, provider.Param2);
    }
}
```

The register these interfaces into the Ioc and inject them into the service handler.

Comment: I like this solution. As far as I see the only downside is that I have to inject all rules into my service regardless of if they are needed or not, because I first know that at runtime when I query the DB.